# qiskit randomly wont import modules

Tags: python, qiskit

I use IBMQ cloud jupyter notebooks and for some reason it suddenly wont import basic modules such as

```
from qiskit import \* 
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Cell In\[2\], line 2
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit.tools'


Use %tb to get the full traceback.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the environment updated the version of `qiskit` that is incompatible with the code you are running in it. You have two options:

- force an installation of a Qiskit compatible version: You can install arbitrary versions of Qiskit in your environment, for example `!pip install qiskit==0.46.0`.
- adapt your code to run with the current version in the environment: In the case you are posting, it seems like the simplest solution, assuming you were expecting a `qiskit 0.*` but you have a `qiskit 1.*` (you can check with `qiskit.__version__`). The function `qiskit.tools.visualization.plot_bloch_multivector` was moved in `qiskit 1.0`, just change the line to `from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector`.